# why controller of old state is getting executed even after state is changed successfully

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Suppose there are two states, A and B.

```
.state("A", {
  url:'/A',
  template: '<div></div>',
  controller: 'ACtrl',
}).state("B", {
  url:'/B',
  template: '<div></div>',
  controller: 'BCtrl',
})
```

And then there are two controllers:

```
.controller('ACtrl',function($state){
    $state.go('B');
    console.log('Why is this getting executed?');
  })
.controller('BCtrl',function($state){

  })
```

Now if am going to url-> /A why the console.log statement is getting executed even after state is changed successfully?

That Controller should stop working. 
Please let me know where am i going wrong.
I just started exploring UI-Router and AngularJs.

Comment: To me it doesn't make much sense to call `$state.go('B')` directly in `ACtrl`'s constructor where it is always executed when the controller is initialized. If the call were wrapped inside a function which is e.g. triggered by a click, you would probably not have this issue.

Comment: @muenchdo actually that was just for representational purpose, consider I want to change the state when stateParams.someId is empty. I hope you will be get what I am trying to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> That Controller should stop working. Please let me know where am i going wrong.

No it should't. There are only few statements/constructs that would act as a code flow control and prevent subsequent code execution. Those are

- [return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)
- [throw](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw)
- [if/else](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)

You don't have anything like this, hence your code gets executed. As expected.

Answer (score 0):

If you implement $state.go in initialization of any controller , than all the methods of that controllers must be called (its the default behavior of controller even if the state are changed). Although it does not make any sense for implementing $state.go in initialization of any controller. But for the sake for understanding, you can check by doing different things. I assumed you got my point.